# Copy log file from Agent to Master Puppet

Tags: puppet, puppetlabs-apache

is there a way in Puppet to copy log file from Puppet Agent to Puppet Master?

Thanks in advance,

Regards,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

solved via filebucket [Resource Type: filebucket](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/types/filebucket.html)